# Msbuild failed only on Jenkins

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, jenkins, msbuild

I have a Xamarin android project in visual studio. When I compile it in Visual Studio it works fine, but when I use jenkins to build it I get that error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.DefaultOutputPaths.targets(20,3): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash($(IntermediateOutputPath))". Method '[MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).  [c:\jenkins\jobs\Build-Android-Supersmart-OsherAd\workspace\com.supersmart.android.osherad\com.supersmart.android.osherad.csproj]

Lately I had upgraded visual studio to 2019 from 2017, but anyway it works inside the visual studio in the Jenkins machine. What am I missing?

I tried to run and restart the machine:

```
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll"

gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.dll"

gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll"

gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll"

gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll"

gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll"
```

[image: My msbuild jenkins configuration]

Comment: Are you sure your jenkins `msbuild` points to msbuild 2019?

Comment: configure msbuild2019 in jenkins settings or fix existing `msbuild`